# Using sympy to solve an equation, python

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I want to solve the below using  Pythons sympy module instead of adapting what if have hand written. The result is x=26.8.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Tks

**EDIT:**

my equation without sympy:

```
def cal_equ(total_vel=1.23, vel_vent_mg=17.74, vel_vent_tg=28.45, const=105):
    a = (const / vel_vent_tg / const) + (1 / vel_vent_mg)
    b = (total_vel - const / vel_vent_tg)
    return b / a
```

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations

Comment: Please add your equation as code, and your best-effort code attempt.  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: def cal_equ(total_vel=1.23, vel_vent_mg=17.74, vel_vent_tg=28.45, const=105):
    a = (const / vel_vent_tg / const) + (1 / vel_vent_mg)
    b = (total_vel - const / vel_vent_tg)
    return b / a

Comment: What is the symbol(s) after `105 -`?

Comment: hi John, not sure what you mean symbol after 105 -. Have read the documentation, just could not fond which method to use. Anyway my function works without sympy. Just thought sympy was a cleaner way to solved

Comment: In your drawing above, the upper-left term appears to be `105 - something`.  What is the something?

Comment: Ahh - its x -> 105-x

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *
# create a symbol: it represents your unkown
x = symbols("x")
# create your constants
total_vel=1.23
vel_vent_mg=17.74
vel_vent_tg=28.45
const=105
# there are many ways to create an equation.
# here we create an equality, something that states that
# the left hand side is equal to the right hand side
eq = Eq((const - x) / vel_vent_tg - x / vel_vent_mg, total_vel)
# finally, we use the solve function to solve for the equation for x
sol = solve(eq, x)
sol[0].n()
# out: 26.8871034856029
```

Comment: @FObersteiner, I realize that a bot has flagged this code-only answer.  But I don't follow the 'future readers' reasoning.  The question provides sufficient context - a request for a sympy solution.   Also the code is commented.  If those lines were non-code, the bot wouldn't have flagged it. Yes, I've learned to include some text to fool the bots, but that doesn't improve the future usefulness of my answers.  I write for the current OP even though most of my reputation comes from future readers.

Comment: @hpaulj please note that he code *wasn't* commented when I added the comment from review, see the edit section. I probably wouldn't have commented if this was the original version. Anyhow, I still think answers benefit from a bit of explanation. If you only do that "to fool the bots", that's kind of sad? But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @FObersteiner, I didn't notice the edits.  If anything my answers are too longwinded, with too much 'teaching' (especially when it comes to the debugging process).  But the future usefulness of an answer depends heavily on how searchable the question is (especially its subject line).  This is a generic sympy request, and the equation is a non-searchable image.